# Create new dataframe column using lapply that is sum of specific columns

Tags: r

Create a dataframe :

```
res <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2), "str" = c(21,15), "c" = c("a1","a2"), "s" = c("s1","s2"), "c1" = c(2,4), "c2" = c(6,8))
```

with values :

```
  ID str  c  s c1 c2
1  1  21 a1 s1  2  6
2  2  15 a2 s2  4  8
```

I'm attempting to create new column `total` with values 8 and 12 which are the totals for c1,c2 for rows with id 1,2

Here attempting to use lapply in order to create the column :

```
lapply(res , sum(c('c1' , 'c2')))
```

but returns error :

```
Error in sum(c("c1", "c2")) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

How to sum specific columns in a data frame ?

Update :

To gain understanding of apply functions I'm attempting to implement using lapply only.

Comment: Isn't this just `rowSums` i.e. `rowSums(res[c('c1', 'c2')])`

Comment: ... or `rowSums(res[, c("c1", "c2")])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data.frames it is usually easier to use `apply`. `lapply`works on vectors. So to use it, you need to transforme the data.frame first with `t` which produces a matrix which you can change to a data.frame. Because `lapply' creates a list you can use unlist to get a vector which you can store into the data.frame from the beginning.

```
res.t = as.data.frame(t(res[,c("c1","c2")]))
res$total = unlist(lapply(res.t, sum))
```

Hope that helps you to understand `lapply`.